# My System.CommandLine app won't build! It can't find a CommandHandler. Do I need to write it?

Tags: c#, system.commandline

I am using VS 2022, .Net 6.0, and trying to build my first app using `System.CommandLine`.

Problem: when I build it, I get an error

> The name 'CommandHandler' does not exist in the current context

The code I'm trying to build is the sample app from the GitHub site: https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/Your-first-app-with-System-CommandLine.md , without alteration (I think).

It looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.CommandLine;
using System.IO;

static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a root command with some options
    var rootCommand = new RootCommand
        { 
        new Option<int>(
            "--int-option",
            getDefaultValue: () => 42,
            description: "An option whose argument is parsed as an int"),
        new Option<bool>(
            "--bool-option",
            "An option whose argument is parsed as a bool"),
        new Option<FileInfo>(
            "--file-option",
            "An option whose argument is parsed as a FileInfo")
    };

    rootCommand.Description = "My sample app";

    // Note that the parameters of the handler method are matched according to the names of the options
    rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<int, bool, FileInfo>((intOption, boolOption, fileOption) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The value for --int-option is: {intOption}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value for --bool-option is: {boolOption}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value for --file-option is: {fileOption?.FullName ?? "null"}");
    });

    // Parse the incoming args and invoke the handler
    return rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args).Result;
}
```

I have installed the latest version of `System.Commandline`: 2.0.0-beta2.21617.1

**SURELY** I am just being a big fat idiot in some respect. But I don't see it.

Any insight would be welcomed.

Comment: I believe, looking at the sample on Github, you're just simply missing a `using System.CommandLine.Invocation;` at the top of your code file ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue is caused by updating the [CommandLine 2.0 Beta 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine) package. Add the reference `System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder` to the references to fix the problem. Follow the announcements on command-line-api's GitHub account:

> In your project, add a reference to System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder.
>
> In your code, change references to the System.CommandLine.Invocation namespace to
> use System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder, where the CommandHandler.Create
> methods are now found. (There’s no longer a CommandHandler type in
> System.CommandLine, so after you update you’ll get compilation errors until you
> reference System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder.)

If you want to continue with the old habits, try using older versions of the `System.CommandLine` package.

---

###### References

- [Announcing System.CommandLine 2.0 Beta 2 and the road to GA](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/1537)

Comment: YES!  The problem was that the CommandHandler has been moved, as you point out, to System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder .

To make things even more confusing, there's now a separate nuGet package for System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder, which must be installed on its own.

Thank, you, I am in business.  This is what we get for using beta tools... but this tool is SO USEFUL

Comment: Has it moved again? I have "#r "nuget: System.CommandLine, 2.0.0-beta4.22272.1" installed in a .NET Interactive notebook and `open System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder` says there's no namespace named "NamingConventionBinder".

Comment: Whelp, of course I answer it as soon as I ask. It is in a separate NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder

Answer (score 2):

Think you are missing a `using` line:

```
using System;
using System.CommandLine;
using System.CommandLine.Invocation;
using System.IO;
```

I can't swear that's it, but it looks like `CommandHandler` is defined in a namespace not referenced by a `using` (in your current code), so `System.CommandLine.Invocation` may be the key!

Comment: Thank you , I tried that, too, but foolishly failed it put it into the sample code. 

Turns out that the furniture had been rearranged, which is to be expected, I suppose, in pre-release code.

Answer (score 0):

To use in this command:

```
System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder
```

You need to write this command it the Terminal:

```
dotnet add package System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder --version 2.0.0-beta4.22272.1
```